# Managed (Release) package upgrade error

Tags: managed-package, gack

I have a release managed package 1.0 installed on my scratch org and now I'm upgrading to 1.1 released managed package but I'm getting this error: what does it mean?

> This app can't be upgraded. There are problems that prevent this
> package from being installed. Install failed  Your requested install
> failed. Please try this again. None of the data or setup information
> in your salesforce.com organization should have been affected by this
> error. If this error persists, contact salesforce.com Support through
> your normal channels and reference number: 1031024430-648351
> (279340770)

Comment: We likely can't help you. You'd have to contact support or other salesforce.com employee to get the reason behind the error.

Comment: Since this is a scratch org, just a hunch, try to open the org and check deployment status, if it can give more details. Also one more thing, pls check the download permission at the profile level.

Comment: I looked and couldn't find any references to this gack. (I'm a Salesforce employee, but not part of the support or managed packaging teams). Being able to reliably reproduce it will help if you choose to open a support case. In the meantime, I'd just delete the scratch org and build a new one with 1.1

Comment: I tried few times and it worked, it must be something with scratch org. thanks all.